# How to read, format, sort, and save a csv file, without pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting, datetime

- Given the following sample data in a file `test.csv`

```py
27-Mar-12,8.25,8.35,8.17,8.19,9801989
26-Mar-12,8.16,8.25,8.12,8.24,8694416
23-Mar-12,8.05,8.12,7.95,8.09,8149170
```

- How can this file be parsed without using `pandas`?

  1. Open the file
  2. Format the date column into a `datetime` date formatted string
  3. Sort all rows by the column 0, the date column
  4. Save back to the same file, with a header for the date column
- With `pandas` this can be accomplished with a single (long) line of code, not including the import.

  - It should be noted, using `parse_date` can be very slow, if `date_parser` isn't used.

```py
import pandas as pd

(pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, parse_dates=[0], date_parser=lambda t: pd.to_datetime(t, format='%d-%b-%y'))
 .rename(columns={0: 'date'})
 .sort_values('date')
 .to_csv('test.csv', index=False))
```

### Expected Form

```py
date,1,2,3,4,5
2012-03-23,8.05,8.12,7.95,8.09,8149170
2012-03-26,8.16,8.25,8.12,8.24,8694416
2012-03-27,8.25,8.35,8.17,8.19,9801989
```

- This question and answer are being written to fill a knowledge content gap on Stack Overflow.
- It's very easy to use `pandas` for this task.
- It was surprisingly difficult to come up with all the necessary pieces to create a complete solution, without `pandas`.
- This should be beneficial for anyone curious about this task, and for students prohibited from using `pandas`.
- I wouldn't mind seeing a solution with `numpy`, but the primary point of the question, is to **accomplish this task with only packages from the standard library**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `pandas` is easier for parsing and cleaning files.

  - What requires 1 line of `pandas`, took 11 lines of code, and requires a `for-loop`.
- This requires the following packages and functions

  - [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) & [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)
  - [Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects): `.seek` & `.truncate`
  - [Sorting: How To](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)
- Initially, `list()` was used to unpack the `csv.reader` object, but that was removed, to update the date value, while iterating through the `reader`.
- A custom key function can be supplied to `sorted` to customize the sort order, but I do not see a way to return a value from the `lambda` expression.

  - Originally `key=lambda row: datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d')` was used, but has been removed, since the updated date column doesn't contain month names.
  - If the date column contains month names, it won't be properly sorted, without a custom sort key.

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime

# open the file for reading and writing
with open('test1.csv', mode='r+', newline='') as f:

   # create a reader and writer opbject
    reader, writer = csv.reader(f), csv.writer(f)
    
    data = list()
    # iterate through the reader and update column 0 to a datetime date string
    for row in reader:

        # update column 0 to a datetime date string
        row[0] = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d-%b-%y").date().isoformat()
        
        # append the row to data
        data.append(row)

    # sort all of the rows, based on date, with a lambda expression
    data = sorted(data, key=lambda row: row[0])

    # change the stream position to the given byte offset
    f.seek(0)

    # truncate the file size
    f.truncate()

    # add a header to data
    data.insert(0, ['date', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

    # write data to the file
    writer.writerows(data)
```

### Updated `test.csv`

```py
date,1,2,3,4,5
2012-03-23,8.05,8.12,7.95,8.09,8149170
2012-03-26,8.16,8.25,8.12,8.24,8694416
2012-03-27,8.25,8.35,8.17,8.19,9801989
```

### `%time` test

```py
import pandas
import pandas_datareader as web

# test data with 1M rows
df = web.DataReader(ticker, data_source='yahoo', start='1980-01-01', end='2020-09-27').drop(columns=['Adj Close']).reset_index().sort_values('High', ascending=False)
df.Date = df.Date.dt.strftime('%d-%b-%y')
df = pd.concat([df]*100)
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

### Tests

```py
# pandas test with date_parser
%time pandas_test('test.csv')
[out]:
Wall time: 17.9 s

# pandas test without the date_parser parameter
%time pandas_test('test.csv')
[out]:
Wall time: 1min 17s

# from Paddy Alton
%time paddy('test.csv')
[out]:
Wall time: 15.9 s

# from Trenton
%time trenton('test.csv')
[out]:
Wall time: 17.7 s

# from sammywemmy with functions updated to return the correct date format
%time sammy('test.csv')
[out]:
Wall time: 22.2 s
%time sammy2('test.csv')
[out]:
Wall time: 22.2 s
```

#### Test Functions

```py
from operator import itemgetter
import csv
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def pandas_test(file):
    (pd.read_csv(file, header=None, parse_dates=[0], date_parser=lambda t: pd.to_datetime(t, format='%d-%b-%y'))
     .rename(columns={0: 'date'})
     .sort_values('date')
     .to_csv(file, index=False))


def trenton(file):
    with open(file, mode='r+', newline='') as f:
        reader, writer = csv.reader(f), csv.writer(f)
        data = list()
        for row in reader:
            row[0] = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d-%b-%y").date().isoformat()
            data.append(row)
        data = sorted(data, key=lambda row: row[0])
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        data.insert(0, ['date', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        writer.writerows(data)


def paddy(file):
    def format_date(date: str) -> str:
        formatted_date = datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%y").date().isoformat()
        return formatted_date


    with open(file, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        records = [[value for value in line.split(",")] for line in lines]
    for record in records:
        record[0] = format_date(record[0])
    sorted_records = sorted(records, key = lambda r: r[0])
    prepared_lines = [",".join(record).strip("\n") for record in sorted_records]
    field_names = "date,1,2,3,4,5"
    prepared_lines.insert(0, field_names)
    prepared_data = "\n".join(prepared_lines)
    with open(file, "w") as f:
        f.write(prepared_data)


def sammy(file):
    # updated with .date().isoformat() to return the correct format
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ["date", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        mapping = list(reader)
        mapping = [
            {
                key: datetime.strptime(value, ("%d-%b-%y")).date().isoformat()
                     if key == "date" else value
                for key, value in entry.items()
            }
            for entry in mapping
        ]

        mapping = sorted(mapping, key=itemgetter("date"))

    with open(file, mode="w", newline="") as csvfile:
        fieldnames = mapping[0].keys()
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        for row in mapping:
            writer.writerow(row)


def sammy2(file):
    # updated with .date().isoformat() to return the correct format
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        mapping = dict(enumerate(reader))
        num_of_cols = len(mapping[0])
        fieldnames = ["date" if n == 0 else n
                      for n in range(num_of_cols)]
        mapping = [
                   [ datetime.strptime(val, "%d-%b-%y").date().isoformat()
                     if ind == 0 else val
                     for ind, val in enumerate(value)
                   ]
                 for key, value in mapping.items()
                  ]

        mapping = sorted(mapping, key=itemgetter(0))

    with open(file, mode="w", newline="") as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        csvwriter.writerow(fieldnames)
        for row in mapping:
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I like the use of `seek` and `truncate`. I've seen a number of questions on SO where people "just want to save" a change to a CSV, and I haven't had a good solution; I always recommend 'read-old, write-new, mv/rename old→new'. I've got this bookmarked, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using as few imports as I can:

```
from datetime import datetime

def format_date(date: str) -> str:

    formatted_date = datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%y").date().isoformat()

    return formatted_date


# read in the CSV
with open("test.csv", "r") as file:

    lines = file.readlines()

    records = [[value for value in line.split(",")] for line in lines]

# reformat the first field in each record
for record in records:
    record[0] = format_date(record[0])

# having formatted the dates, sort records by first (date) field:
sorted_records = sorted(records, key = lambda r: r[0])

# join values with commas once more, removing newline characters
prepared_lines = [",".join(record).strip("\n") for record in sorted_records]

# create a header row
field_names = "date,1,2,3,4,5"

# prepend the header row
prepared_lines.insert(0, field_names)

prepared_data = "\n".join(prepared_lines)

# write out the CSV
with open("test.csv", "w") as file:
    file.write(prepared_data)
```

Comment: You could skip the `.strip("\n")` and `"\n".join()` and then use `file.write(field_names+"\n")` followed by `file.writelines(prepared_lines)`.

Comment: Definitely a few ways to manage the read/write bits of the code, and that would be shorter. Also, in retrospect perhaps `format_date` should have taken a record as input and formatted its first element to allow the more elegant `formatted_records = list(map(format_date, records))` in place of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP states, Pandas makes this easy; an alternative is to use the [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) options; it still is more verbose than using Pandas (beauty of abstraction here, Pandas does the heavy lifting for us).

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from operator import itemgetter

with open("test.csv") as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ["date", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    mapping = list(reader)
    mapping = [
        {
            key: datetime.strptime(value, ("%d-%b-%y"))
                 if key == "date" else value
            for key, value in entry.items()
        }
        for entry in mapping
    ]

    mapping = sorted(mapping, key=itemgetter("date"))

with open("test.csv", mode="w", newline="") as csvfile:
    fieldnames = mapping[0].keys()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in mapping:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Since the fieldnames are not known ahead of time, we could use the [csvreader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and [csvwriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) options:

```
with open("test.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    mapping = dict(enumerate(reader))
    num_of_cols = len(mapping[0])
    fieldnames = ["date" if n == 0 else n
                  for n in range(num_of_cols)]
    mapping = [
               [ datetime.strptime(val, "%d-%b-%y")
                 if ind == 0 else val
                 for ind, val in enumerate(value)
               ]
             for key, value in mapping.items()
              ]

    mapping = sorted(mapping, key=itemgetter(0))

with open("test.csv", mode="w", newline="") as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    csvwriter.writerow(fieldnames)
    for row in mapping:
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide an updated answer, because I think the current answers give the impression that reading a CSV file using the standard library is overly complex.

Although Pandas does provide some nice convenience functions, this task isn't particularly difficult in using the standard library.

Here is an example:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open('data.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [
        (datetime.strptime(row[0], '%d-%b-%y'), *row[1:])
        for row in reader
    ]

header = [f'{idx:d}' for idx in range(len(data[0]))]
header[0] = 'date'
with open('sorted_data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
    writer.writerow(header)
    for row in sorted(data):
        writer.writerow((row[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), *row[1:]))
```

Compared to Pandas, the standard library might be a bit more complex, but not overly so. Also, the user also has more control of what's going on, especially with the output.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer = 'data.csv',
    header = None,
)
df = df.rename(columns={0: 'date'})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%b-%y')
df_sorted = df.sort_values('date')
df_sorted.to_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer = 'sorted_data.csv',
    index = False,
)
```

Pandas is great, but for simple tasks like this, I'll argue that it's a pretty heavy import.

Answer (score -1):

This sorting/formatting task can be accomplished in [mlr](https://github.com/johnkerl) without any coding, kind of ;)

```
cat nopanda.csv
27-Mar-12,8.25,8.35,8.17,8.19,9801989
26-Mar-12,8.16,8.25,8.12,8.24,8694416
23-Mar-12,8.05,8.12,7.95,8.09,8149170
```

```
brew install miller

mlr --csv --ofs ',' --implicit-csv-header label date,1,2,3,4,5 then put '$date=strftime(strptime($date, "%d-%b-%y"), "%Y-%m-%d");' then sort -f date nopanda.csv

date,1,2,3,4,5
2012-03-23,8.05,8.12,7.95,8.09,8149170
2012-03-26,8.16,8.25,8.12,8.24,8694416
2012-03-27,8.25,8.35,8.17,8.19,9801989
```

See documentation:

- https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/csv-with-and-without-headers/

Comment: This does not answer the question in the OP, which states _... the primary point of the question, is to accomplish this task **with only packages from the standard library**._ Please review [answer], and answer the question that is asked.

Comment: The question does not mention that the solution must be implemented in python.

Comment: I believe there is some value in knowing that there are other options for "data processing" than python, peace :)

Comment: The tag specifies python, that’s what the tags are for. And the standard library is specified as well.

Comment: There are existing questions on SO, where a command line option is appropriate.